# Identifying sub rows using TableBuilder - GWT 2.5

Tags: gwt, css, gwt-celltable, gwt-2.5

When building a celltable using a TableBuilder, I encounter a problem to set a unique class name to sub rows. (gwt 2.5RC)

the code that builds the rows looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void buildRowImpl(AdGroupProxy mainAdGroup, int absRowIndex) {

    super.buildRowImpl(mainAdGroup, absRowIndex);

    for (AdGroupProxy adGroup : mainAdGroup.getChildren()) {

        super.buildRowImpl(adGroup, ++absRowIndex);

    }
}
```

Every `<tr>` been generated inside the loop is a subrow.

The `<tr>`'s are generated with the attribute `__gwt_subrow=1`,`__gwt_subrow=2` ...

however, due to the issue of [GWT isn't supporting CSS3](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7274) I cannot use the following selector to select the sub rows:

`.dataGridOddRow:not([__gwt_subrow="0"])`

I don't want neither to implement the method `buildRowImpl` myself.

Any suggestions of how to set a class name to sub rows only?

Comment: can you add a little code to your questions to get a better context of what you are doing?

Comment: similar to John Labanca [custom table](http://showcase2.jlabanca-testing.appspot.com/#!CwCustomDataGrid), I build a table with sub rows.

John implemented the build of the row himself, I'm trying to avoid doing so, but still to control the styling of the sub rows VS main rows.

my code and his code are pretty similar, except I use the Default `buildRowImpl` method because it performs exactly what I need.